# How can I get gps location updates at an specific rate?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm developing an application that needs to get location updates fast, doesn't matter the accuracy of them. I need to be able to get about one reading per second. How can I do this?

Comment: What for? Does it matter if you get the same location for 30 times?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter. Plus if for whatever reason it changes providers accuracy and location might vary widely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than specifying `0` for both the minimum distance and minimum time values in `requestLocationUpdates()`, you have no control over the rate. Android will give you all of the fixes it receives, but whether that is 30 fixes per second or 30 seconds per fix will depend upon hardware, environment (e.g., is the user indoors?), and so forth.

Comment: Are you possitively sure of this?

Comment: Yes, and specifying 0 for both min distance and min time will put a load on your battery life coz the gps sensor will keep requesting for location updates every second! and even if the user's location is not at all changed!

Answer (score 2):

You could build a layer between the Android location updates and your receiver.
In your own layer, catch the Android location updates, and pass the same location 30 times per second to your receiver, until you get a new location.

**EDIT**
Something like this (not tested):

```
public class MyLocationManager implements LocationListener{

    private List<MyLocationListener> listeners;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Handler handler;

    public MyLocationManager(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        listeners = new ArrayList<MyLocationListener>();
        handler = new Handler();

        sendLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void sendDelayedLocationUpdates(){
        handler.postDelayed(locationUpdater, 200);
    }

    public void addMyLocationListener(MyLocationListener mListener){
        listeners.add(mListener);
    }

    public void removeMyLocationListener(MyLocationListener mListener){
        listeners.remove(mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;
    }

    public interface MyLocationListener{
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location);
    }

    private Runnable locationUpdater = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                for(MyLocationListener mListener : listeners){
                    mListener.onLocationChanged(lastLocation);
                }

                sendDelayedLocationUpdates();
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: An example: Create a `LocationListener` that stores the data you need in some variables. Then create a timer (there are many different ways to do this) the rate you need and do what ever you need to with that data. You will be getting a consistent speed of updates, but the updates will most likely not change most of the time (i.e., between actual GPS location updates). (If you are doing multithreading, be sure to design your code accordingly!)

Comment: See the edit. You might need to implement some housekeeping for the `LocationListener` to start and stop.

Comment: Will work on this and get back to you. Would this esentially just repeat the last know location several times?

Comment: Yes, as CommonsWare said, you *are* depending on hardware.

Comment: Oh well, guess there is no way about it. Thanks any ways.